# Spotfire connection with MySql

Tags: mysql, database-connection, spotfire

I have been trying to use MySql data with Spotfire, Had a connection established and managed to make a working dxp file. Tried to do the same with a second table and it threw this error

The following error message "Streaming result set com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic@XXXXXX is still active. No statements may be issued when any streaming result sets are open and in use on a given connection. Ensure that you have called .close() on any active streaming result sets before attempting more queries" comes from MySQL.

afterwards I opened my already working dxp file and the error popped again. It seems I somehow have a connection still open and active but spotfire is suppose to manage the connection as far as I know at least

After looking this up online some people say it's a bug, others say I need to close the connection, but I can't find a solution. Please help

Edit: changing the minimum connections number (which probably closes the open connections) makes ot possible for the dxp to run once but then it fails the second time (after closing and opening)

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution? It looks like it is a known limitation of mysql but 'not a bug' [https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=39156](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=39156)

Comment: I haven't been able to find a solution other than changing DB.